# Is there a Chamfer modifier like 3d max in blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, bevel

I am 3d max user and i am used to chamfer and turbosmooth workflow in 3dmax.  The chamfer modifier in max takes into account the smoothing groups and bevel edges accordingly. Then adding turbosmooth on top gives you sharp and smooth edges.Is there a workflow or tool to replicated the same in blender?[image]

Comment: I don't know 3ds max, but I think what you want is 'bevel' modifier

Comment: The bevel modifier does not have the feature to take in smoothing groups defined by user?

Comment: You should try to describe at least with an image the desired worflow in 3ds max, better with a before/after comparison for each tool used...

Comment: i think it should be clear now!

Comment: The bevel modifier supports Creases (Shift E) as well as vertex groups when set to the "Weight group" mode. If you want to apply the bevel anyways (as in yoir image) use the bevel operation (Ctrl B) in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

The bevel modifier is what you're looking for.  The other answers don't mention that it can be set to use only bevel weights defined by the user.  Bevel weights can be set for each individual edge and smaller weight = smaller radius bevel.

Answer (score 0):

There is the bevel modifier in Blender that works a similar way. The smoothing groups do not affect the shape, there is the profile setting there and if it the profile is set to 0.5, then the bevel is perfect circular shape.